# No consistent EXIF data stored in pictures taken with nativescript-camera plugin (^4.0.2) on Samsung Galaxy S7

Tags: camera, metadata, nativescript, exif, galaxy

The nativescript-camera plugin won't save any EXIF data in pictures on a Samsung Galaxy S7 whereas the Samsung camera app behaves / save them normally. 
I am trying with the ^4.0.2 version.

I also tried my app on a Motorola G3, and the metadata are properly written in the picture (??).

Any clue about what's wrong and a possible fix ? (Thanks)

I thought the plugin should expose all the camera functions and preferences as set in the main camera app, but it seems not the case for the Galaxy S7..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to a nativescript-camera plugin fellow, this is a known issue that can occur from one mobile phone vendor to another. Samsung Galaxy S7 won't let write through a third party app, EXIF metadata as freely as other vendors may let, or their proprietary app may do..

Depending the needed data, values may therefore not always be extracted from the images saved through nativescript-camera module, for now.

In order to keep consistent results across all platforms, EXIF data can hereby and unfortunately not be trusted for the moment with the nativescript-camera module alone (CLI 4.2.4, plugin version ^4.0.2), even if very complete on likely most other vendor's targets.

Answer (score 0):

The camera plugin is responsible only for capturing the image. If you like to extract the exif meta data from the given image, there are few android libraries which does the job for you, for instance [metadata-extractor](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the problem is not about extracting the data. The app is not writing any EXIF data in the image in my case. On the Galaxy S7 Edge, the data is not written at all when taking picture from the nativescript app, whereas the proprietary camera app of the phone manages to write them properly. The problem is likely not occurring on other phones / brands..

Comment: Were you able to debug inside the plugin and see whether rotateBitmap method (https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-camera/blob/master/src/camera.android.ts#L120-L126) is called to update the actual orientation of the image?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I will try that. So failure of such method could be at the origin of failing to write the rest of the EXIF tags, or something ?

Comment: Yes, at least from my readings it is possible that EXIF data might be lost while rewriting the image. You may disable those rewrite and see if that helps. If then, there are options to retain EXIF data which you may worry about later.

Comment: Ah great, thanks, now I understand why there were so much mentions about the image orientation issue while struggling in finding a solution on forums.. Since I just needed lat/long coordinates, I am directly using the geolocation module for now, instead of extracting the coordinates from the picture. But it is good to know where the problem possibly come from and where to inspect, in case I finally need to do something else with the EXIF data later on. So thanks again / have a nice day.